# Problem With A Rock Paper Scissors Game In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Calling all coders, wish you all the best on your respective coding journeys!

I'm currently making a rock, paper, scissors game (traditional, I know) in Python. Everything so far is going so expected, except for one thing. While I was coding, I figured that I should set up a scoring limit for both the player and the CPU, which is 5 (as you will see below) to prevent a semi-infinite loop from occuring. And I did. However, when either the computer's score or the player's score reaches 5, the game doesn't stop, instead it continues to ask the player for his choice (rock, paper, or scissors), even if I had already set up conditions to stop, or break out of, the game after that occurs. Here is the code for reference

```
# Rock, Paper, Scissors
import random

choices = ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors")
player_score = 0
computer_score = 0
playing = False
score_limit = 5

play = input("Do you want to play? (y/n): ")

if play in ["y", "yes"]:
    playing = True
elif play in ["n", "no"]:
    playing = False
else:
    raise Exception("Invalid input")

while playing:
        player = input("Enter your choice: ")
        computer = random.choice(choices)

        if player == "Rock":
            if computer == "Paper":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                computer_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
                continue
            if computer == "Scissors":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                player_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
                continue

        elif player == "Paper":
            if computer == "Rock":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                player_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
                continue
            if computer == "Scissors":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                computer_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
                continue

        elif player == "Scissors":
            if computer == "Rock":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                computer_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
                continue
            if computer == "Paper":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                player_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
                continue

        if player == computer:
            print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
            print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
            print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
            continue

        elif player not in choices:
            raise Exception("Invalid input.")

        if player_score == score_limit or computer_score == score_limit:
            print("Game ended")
            break
```

Comment: You just need to remove all the `continue` statements from within the `while playing:` loop. Those statements always skip over the test for the end of the game.

Comment: `continue` ends the current iteration of the loop and goes back to the start. So it prevents the code that checks the score from ever being run.

Answer (score 3):

The code is never reached because you use `continue` after every possibility. You can fix this by removing them and replacing your consecutive `if` statements with `elif`.

example:

```
while playing:
        player = input("Enter your choice: ")
        computer = random.choice(choices)

        if player == "Rock":
            if computer == "Paper":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                computer_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
            elif computer == "Scissors":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                player_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))

        elif player == "Paper":
            if computer == "Rock":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                player_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
            elif computer == "Scissors":
                print("Computer's choice: {}".format(computer))
                computer_score += 1
                print("Your score: {}".format(player_score))
                print("Computer's score: {}".format(computer_score))
```

Comment: I keep adding continue statements to prevent infinite loops, FYI.

Comment: A `continue` won't prevent an infinite loop - in fact, mistaken use of `continue` will *cause* infinite loops, like the one in your question. Ask yourself if you 100% understand what `continue` and `break` do: if not, it would be great to get that really nailed down in your mind.

Comment: @DRCherryBomb - Your loop is not infinite. You have a condition that breaks the loop. Your code is not reaching that condition because you keep going to the next iteration of the loop before it can get to it. My answer is correct.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I should take that into consideration then. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

You already have a direct answer to your question. However, you might find the following refactored version of your code to be helpful. In particular, I've reorganized the while loop's logic so that you're not giving instructions redundantly.

```
import random

def judge(player, computer):
    wins = [("Rock","Scissors"),
            ("Scissors","Paper"),
            ("Paper","Rock")]
    if player == computer:
        return "tie"
    if (player,computer) in wins:
        return "win"
    return "lose"

choices = ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors")
player_score = 0
computer_score = 0
playing = False
score_limit = 5

play = input("Do you want to play? (y/n): ")

if play in ["y", "yes"]:
    playing = True
elif play in ["n", "no"]:
    playing = False
else:
    raise Exception("Invalid input")

while playing:
    player = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if player not in choices:
        raise Exception("Invalid input.")
    
    computer = random.choice(choices)
    print(f"Computer's choice: {computer}")
    outcome = judge(player, computer)
    
    if outcome == "win":
        player_score += 1
    elif outcome == "lose":
        computer_score += 1
    
    print(f"Your score: {player_score}")
    print(f"Computer's score: {computer_score}\n")
    
    if score_limit in [player_score, computer_score]:
        print("Game ended")
        break
```

Comment: So nice, clean, and trimmed. Thanks for sharing! Might try.

Comment: Also, just asking, is it really not necessary to put the return "lose" line inside of an else statement?

Comment: @DR It is not. The return statement of each if block ensures that we don’t accidentally hit the “lose” statement